# jQuery - Hide element before animate hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm currently using this little jQuery snippet to fade in/out a div when I hover over a particular element.

```
$(".wall-block-content").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},300); //stop for preveting conflict
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0'},300); //100 for time/speed
});
```

It works fine apart from the fact that the ".wall-block-content" div is visible on page load, when I need it to be hidden.

Here is some sample markup in case that helps;

```
<div class="grid-block">

   <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg"/>

    <div class="wall-block-content">

        <!-- SOME FANCY CONTENT HERE -->

    </div><!--/.wall-block-content-->

</div><!--/.grid-block-->
```

So basically all that is visible on page load is the thumbnail.jpg image and then when someone hovers over that image the .wall-block-content div fades in on top of it...

Any ideas?

Comment: do you hide it with display:none or opacity:0 by css ?

Comment: Neither. If I use either CSS rules the animate function doesn't work...

Comment: it will work if you set opacity to 0 by css. Or use show().animate ... and .animate().hide()

Answer (score 1):

Using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` would be better.

```
$('#imgtest').hover(function(){
    $('.wall-block-content').fadeIn('slow');

},function(){
    $('.wall-block-content').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ew4xq/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the jQuery-functions .fadeIn() and .fadeOut()?

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

To your question:
    `.wall-block-content {
        display: none;
    }`

Comment: jQuery really isn't my strong suit. How would I use that with hover?

Comment: $('.grid-block img').hover(function(){
    $('.wall-block-content').fadeIn('slow');

},function(){
    $('.wall-block-content').fadeOut('slow');
});

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.wall-block-content {display:none}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#imgtest').hover(function(){
    $('.wall-block-content').fadeToggle();
});
```

you can also add a duration like fadeToggle('slow')